# Add glyphicon to angular-ui alert

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, alert, angular-ui

I'm trying to add a glyphicon to a default Angular-UI Bootstrap style alert. I'm playing with the Plunker here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/KeI1gGqa46d3lptIcoF9?p=preview

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
<div class="alert alert-warning">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span>
    <span>What I want!</span>
</div>
```

How can I have the image and the message on one line?

**Resolution Update:**
http://plnkr.co/edit/8YEC5B3Vxp7soWlNBASa?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ui bootstrap `Alert` uses transclusion so just provide it within the directive element. i.e

```
<alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span> 
     <!--<span ng-class="alert.img"></span> -->
    {{alert.msg}}
</alert>
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/wI2gbz?p=preview)**

or if you want to avoid repeating this and need this across your application you can as well override the template in the run block in your module and update it to match your needs, i.e do:

```
app.run(['$templateCache',function($templateCache){
  $templateCache.put("template/alert/alert.html",
    "<div class=\"alert\" ng-class=\"['alert-' + (type || 'warning'), closeable ? 'alert-dismissable' : null]\" role=\"alert\">\n" +
    "    <button ng-show=\"closeable\" type=\"button\" class=\"close\" ng-click=\"close()\">\n" +
    "        <span aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</span>\n" +
    "        <span class=\"sr-only\">Close</span>\n" +
    "    </button>\n" +
    "    <div><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign'></span>&nbsp;<span ng-transclude></span></div>\n" +
    "</div>");
}]);
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/VkxSoN?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks.  I'm trying to add a different glyphicon to each type of alert.  But the icon creates a line break. See the updated Plunker.

Comment: @duyn9uyen As i explained in my first option just do it this way.. http://plnkr.co/edit/T4q9rA?p=preview. i.e `<span ng-class="alert.img"></span>{{alert.msg}}`